# Material UI Switch toggle has bugs and doesn't change properly

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have created a simple React project where I have inserted a Material UI switch in the drawer of my app that toggles the theme of the app from dark to light. The problem is sometimes when I load the app and click the switch, it doesn't respond the first few times. And when I keep clicking, it then changes the theme but the behavior is flipped: the way I made the switch is that the switch is checked/on when it is dark mode and off when it is light, but now, after not responding for the first few times, it changes the behavior and it is on when it is light mode and vice versa.

The way I am toggling the switch is this:

states that I used:

```
  const [isDark, setDarkMode] = React.useState(true);
  const [theme, setTheme] = React.useState(darkTheme);
```

toggleTheme function:

```
const toggleTheme = () => {
    setDarkMode((prev) => !prev);
    setTheme(isDark ? darkTheme : lightTheme);
  };
```

and here is my switch:

```
<Switch edge="start" checked={isDark} onChange={toggleTheme} />
```

EDIT:  And this issue still persists if i do this instead:

```
setTheme((prev) => prev === darkTheme? lightTheme: darkTheme);
```

Result: (behavior is still flipped)

[image]

Code:

[image]

My CodeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-karmapact-app-bghgp?file=/App.js

Answer (score 1):

You need to invert the theme toggle `setTheme(isDark ? darkTheme : lightTheme);`

If current is dark theme then you want to set the light them, and vice versa.

```
const toggleTheme = () => {
  setDarkMode((prev) => !prev);
  setTheme(isDark ? lightTheme : darkTheme);
};
```

Comment: But isn't the setTheme after setDarkMode which means that isDark has been altered too. so if it is true then it would be dark and light if false. And this issue still persists if i do this instead: setTheme((prev) => prev === darkTheme? lightTheme: darkTheme);

Comment: @AyushKoul React state is const throughout a render cycle, and state updates are asynchronous. `setDarkMode((prev) => !prev);` toggles the `isDark` state for the *next* render cycle, so it is still its current value for the duration of the *current* render cycle. Don't worry, this is a common misunderstanding with react, functional components, and `useState` hooks, and more generally, the entire react component lifecycle.

Comment: I see. thank! Also, could you explain what the issue with the second method is where i set the theme using its previous state?

Comment: @AyushKoul Ah, sure, sorry I missed that bit of your question. I swapped the commented code (`setTheme((prev) => (prev === darkTheme ? lightTheme : darkTheme));`) and reloaded the app and it seems to function as expected in the codesandbox. I even dropped a `console.log('prev === darkTheme', prev === darkTheme)` in the `setTheme` callback and see it toggle true/false as expected.

Comment: I tried the same code and it still doesn't function for me. Sometimes when I open it, it works but it still does not function 100% of the time. I have added a pic under my question's EDIT to show you.

Comment: @AyushKoul I've tried combinations of reloading the page, reloading the entire sandbox... for me it seemingly consistently toggles the theme as expected without issue. In your sandbox, what are your reproduction steps? Also, do you need to use the current theme object for comparison (are you trying to remove the `isDark` state)?

Comment: what do you mean my reproduction steps? Also, your method works and I will finally do it your way. The reason I was asking about using the prevState of theme is a) that way it will not depend on any other state and I won't have to worry about the async nature that you mentioned  and b) I wanted to know why it is not working for future reference so that I don't make that mistake again. I have updated my sandbox to use this and the link is in my question. Please try to run it there and see if it still behaves this way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222105/discussion-between-ayush-koul-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably with your function:

```js
const toggleTheme = () => {
  setDarkMode((prev) => !prev);
  setTheme(isDark ? darkTheme : lightTheme);
};
```

It should be as following:

```js
const toggleTheme = () => {
  setDarkMode((prev) => !prev);
  setTheme(isDark ? lightTheme : darkTheme); // this condition should be changed
};
```

Comment: I see. Thanks! Although, as I stated in the previous answer's comments too, why doesn't using the previous state of the theme work? Code (See my question's EDIT): setTheme((prev) => (prev === darkTheme ? lightTheme : darkTheme));

Comment: can you tell me what the `prev` is?
I mean the value inside :)

Comment: prev holds the previous value of the state. So in the case of setTheme, it will be the previous value of theme

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the work of `React.StrictMode`. It is a currently a [bug as of Material-UI Release 4.11.0](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/20708). In short, you are going to want to take out `React.StrictMode` to test the switching of themes.

Example of the Bug when using `React.StrictMode`:

```js
const darkTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "dark",
    primary: {
      main: "#ffffff"
    }
  }
});

const lightTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "light",
    primary: {
      main: "#000000"
    }
  }
});

function App() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(darkTheme);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline>
        <ButtonGroup>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            onClick={() => {
              setTheme(lightTheme);
            }}
          >
            Light
          </Button>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            onClick={() => {
              setTheme(darkTheme);
            }}
          >
            Dark
          </Button>
        </ButtonGroup>

        <Typography color="primary">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
          since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
          scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
          five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
          remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
          the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
          more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
          including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </Typography>
      </CssBaseline>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@4.11.0/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>
  <script type="text/babel">
    const {
      createMuiTheme,
      ThemeProvider,
      Typography,
      Button,
      ButtonGroup,
      CssBaseline
    } = MaterialUI;
    const { useState } = React;
  </script>
</body>
```

As an alternative solution in addition to taking out `React.StrictMode`, it seems to work as well when you shallowly clone `theme`, e.g., `<ThemeProvider theme={{...theme}}>`

```js
const darkTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "dark",
    primary: {
      main: "#ffffff"
    }
  }
});

const lightTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "light",
    primary: {
      main: "#000000"
    }
  }
});

function App() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(darkTheme);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={{...theme}}>
      <CssBaseline>
        <ButtonGroup>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            onClick={() => {
              setTheme(lightTheme);
            }}
          >
            Light
          </Button>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            onClick={() => {
              setTheme(darkTheme);
            }}
          >
            Dark
          </Button>
        </ButtonGroup>

        <Typography color="primary">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
          since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
          scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
          five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
          remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
          the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
          more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
          including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </Typography>
      </CssBaseline>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@4.11.0/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>
  <script type="text/babel">
    const {
      createMuiTheme,
      ThemeProvider,
      Typography,
      Button,
      ButtonGroup,
      CssBaseline
    } = MaterialUI;
    const { useState } = React;
  </script>
</body>
```